# Add elements to another list that complies a certain condition in Prolog

Tags: list, filter, prolog, element

Hello I want to make a program in Prolog where it's given a list as an input and the result is the list but only with the elements that obey a certain condition.
Example:
Output all elements < 6.

filter([1,6,4,9,13,5,2],X).
--> X = [1,4,5,2].

I've tried to do this:

```
filter([],[]).
filter([P|R], X) :-
    P < 6,
    filter(R, [P|X]).
```

Why doesn't this work?
I know I can use findall but I'd like to understand this 'manual' method.
Thank you

Comment: you need to specify what to do if the condition is not true (P >= 6)

Comment: Use [include/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3)